# string variable interpolation

Tags: bash, sh, jq

I've coded this script:

```
for i in `seq 1 $1`; do
        timestamp=$(uuidgen)
        cat $2.json | jq '.transactionId = "$timestamp"' > $3/$timestamp.json
done
```

My issue is on `jq '.transactionId = "$timestamp"'` since the content of file is:

```
{
  "transactionId": "$timestamp"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You mentioned you have an issue with a particular line. Could you tell us what the issue is and why it is an issue?

Comment: Just change single quotes for double quotes: `jq "... '$timestamp'"`

Comment: As an aide, avoid the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and [quote all your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 6):

There are better ways to pass variables to `jq`:

```
$ cat data.test
{
  "foo": "noooo"
}
$ new=bar
$ jq --arg new_foo "$new" '.foo |= $new_foo' data.test
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: in this case, wouldn't `=` be enough rather than `|=` ?